# Transform result of a table via subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table in a header\details format . All rows that have Rw_Type =D are headers and the immediately following lines are the details of that line  Rw_Type =M  of that line until the next Rw_Type =D which represents a new Header.

There is always a single header with multiple rows representing the details

```
  CREATE TABLE #Tbl
  ( 
    Serial VARCHAR(100),
    Rw INT ,
    Rw_Type VARCHAR(1),
    Decrip_Article  VARCHAR(max),
    Is_Article VARCHAR(1)
  ) 

INSERT INTO #Tbl ( Serial, Rw, Rw_Type, Decrip_Article, Is_Article)
VALUES( '0000265954',   '30',   'D',    'ORD.2023217BaltiniBAL7700070861','.' ),                  
('0000265954',  '40',   'M',    '36200 - JEANS size : 4 color :0224','*'  ),                  
('0000265954',  '60',   'D',    'ORD.2023217BaltiniBAL7700070898','.'   ),                 
('0000265954',  '70',   'M',    'AAUBT0002FA01 - BELT size : 01 color :GR','*'   ),         
('0000265954',  '70',   'M',    'AAUBT0002FA01 - BELT size : 05 color :RR','*'  ),             
('0000265954',  '90',   'D' ,'ORD.2023217BaltiniBAL7700070887 ' ,   '.'    ),               
('0000265954',  '100',  'M' ,'PERGSA049CR0010 - SHOULDERBAG size : 01 ','*'  ), 
('0000265954',  '100',  'M' ,'PERGSA049CR0010 - SHOULDERBAG size : 02 ','*' ),  
('0000265954',  '100',  'M' ,'PERGSA049CR0010 - SHOULDERBAG size : 03 ','*'  );
```

My goal is transform thi stable in this way:

[image]

I tried to proceed via subquery, but I wasn't successful. Any suggestions?
Always grateful for any help

```
 select e.Serial, e.Rw,(
    select min(e1.Rw) from 
        #tbl e1 
        where e1.Serial= e.Serialand 
        e1.Type_Row = 'D' and 
        e1.Rw> e.Rw 
     ) AS c
    
    from #Tbl e 
    where e.Type_Row = 'M'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *gaps and islands* problem that can be addressed by employing a running total to allocate a unique identifier to each group of successive rows that have Rw_Type = D following by rows with Rw_Type = M :

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN Rw_Type = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY Serial ORDER BY Rw ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as grp
  FROM #Tbl
)
SELECT c1.Serial, c1.Rw as Header_row, c1.Rw_Type as Header_Type_row, c1.Decrip_Article as Header, 
       c2.Rw as Details_article_row, c2.Rw_Type as Details_article_type_row, c2.Decrip_Article as Details_article
FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2 on c1.Serial = c2.Serial and c1.grp = c2.grp and c2.Rw_Type = 'M'
WHERE c1.Rw_Type = 'D';
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Flw4ozhb)

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a fancier way to do this, but I would use a temp table to first group the items together and identify the header rows.  I would then just cross apply to get the details.

I would not use a CTE as you will hit it twice doing it this way.  But this is a good start to get what you are asking for:

```
SELECT * 
,SUM(CASE WHEN rw_type = 'D' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Serial Order by Rw ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) GrpID
INTO #Header
from #tbl

SELECT t1.Serial,t1.rw,t1.Decrip_Article, CA.Rw,CA.Rw_Type,CA.Decrip_Article
FROM #Header t1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT * from #Header t2 WHERE t2.GrpID = t1.GrpID and t2.Rw_Type = 'M') CA
WHERE t1.Rw_Type = 'D'
```

Answer (score 1):

Acquire the most recent D for every M in a sub query then join to Ms

```
select t.serial,t.rw,t.rw_type,t.decrip_article,
        s.rw,s.rw_type,s.decrip_article
from #tbl t
join
(select t.*,
        (select top 1 rw from #tbl t1 where t1.rw < t.rw and t1.rw_type = 'D' order by t1.rw desc) prw
from #tbl t
where rw_type = 'M'
)s on s.prw = t.rw
where t.rw_type = 'D'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/F4OZ48A1

Answer (score 1):

Again, a simple solution that may not be the most well written or efficient but does work..

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * , LEAD(Rw, 1, 999999) OVER(PARTITION BY Serial ORDER BY Rw) as NextRow FROM #tbl WHERE Rw_Type = 'D') hdr 
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM #tbl WHERE Rw_Type = 'M') det
        ON hdr.Serial = det.Serial
        AND det.Rw between hdr.rw and hdr.NextRow
    ORDER by hdr.Rw, det.rw
```

Uses a subquery to get header 'boundaries' and then a simple join to get the details.

Answer (score 0):

We select the fields you need. We are joining:

- `d`: The previous D record
- `next_d`: The next D record (or all null for the last element)
- `betw_d`: Any D record between `d` and `next_d`, we look for `betw_d` records and we consider a (`d`, `next_d`) tuple to be valid if and only if no D record is between them, as filtered in the `where` clause
- `betw_m`: Any M record between `d` and `next_d`

```
select <yourfields>
from #Tbl d
left join #Tbl next_d
on d.Rw_Type = next_d.Rw_Type and d.Rw < next_d.Rw
left join #Tbl betw_d
on d.Rw_Type = betw_d.Rw_type and d.Rw < betw_s.Rw and betw.Rw < next_d.Rw
join #Tbl betw_m
on betw_m.Rw_Type = 'M' and d.Rw < betw_m.Rw
where ((betw.Rw is null) or (next_d.Rw is null)) and
      ((next_d.Rw is null) or (betw_m.Rw < next_d.Rw)) and
      (d.Rw_Type = 'D')
```

Here we `join` with the M records and that will filter out any D record that has no follow-up M records. If you do want to have follow-up M records, then use `left join` instead.